# JavaScript function inside echo in PHP script is not calling

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a problem with calling function "adding" inside "a" tag in eho of PHP script. After click in button function is not calling. I have not any idea. How to solve it?

```
<?php
                require_once 'connect.php';
                $statement=$db->query('SELECT * FROM Items');
                foreach($statement as $row)
                    {
                        $item="item_".$row[0];
                        $view="view".$row[0];
                        $image=$row[1];
                        $name=$row[2];
                        $price=$row[3];
                        $plus="+";
                        $minus="-";

                       echo "<tr>
                        <td class='cart_product'>
                            <a href=''><img src='images/cart/$image' alt=''></a>
                        </td>
                        <td class='cart_description'>
                            <h4><a href=''>$name</a></h4>
                        </td>
                        <td class='cart_price'>
                            <p>$$price</p>
                        </td>
                        <td class='cart_quantity'>
                            <div class='cart_quantity_button'>
                                <a class='cart_quantity_up' href='' onclick='adding($plus, $item);'> + </a>
                                <input class='cart_quantity_input' type='text' name=$item id=$item value='0' autocomplete='off' size='2'>
                                <a class='cart_quantity_down' href='javascript:adding($minus, $item); sumitem($item, $price, $view);'> - </a>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class='cart_total'>
                            <p style='width: 5em' class='cart_total_price' id=$view >$0</p>
                        </td>
                        <td class='cart_delete'>
                            <a class='cart_quantity_delete' href='javascript:reset($item, $view)'><i class='fa fa-times'></i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>";
                    }
                    ?>
```

Comment: How do you know the JavaScript function isn’t invoking?  Are you clicking the ‘+’ or on the parent div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call JavaScript function and send variables to it like this:

```
<script>
function myFunc(var1){
    alert(var1);
}
</script>

<?php
    $var1= "\"test string\"";
    echo "<a href='' onclick='myFunc($var1);'>Link to Click</a>";
?>
```

your variables sending is wrong.

Comment: He is echoing a whole block of HTML. The variables are being passed in OPs code in exactly the same way as your example.

Comment: The difference is here: $var1= "\"test string\"";

Comment: Thank you, that's helped so much. Why I need to use this form?

Comment: your welcome ;)
because the '+' and other string variables must be in the quotations, so the js function can get the string values correctly, otherwise js function get those as non-string variables and values don't have any mean to function.

Comment: @SajjadSo yes, I see now what you’re saying. In OPs original post he’s not passing string values to the JS function. Good spot!